# Translation of OpenGL ES 2.0 Shapes in Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, transform

I recently looked at the OpenGL ES 2.0 Tutorial provided by developers.android.com. I succesfully finished it (even if it wasn't very clear) but then I bumped into a problem. Once I finished it, I was never told how to translate or scale objects. I tried different options that seemed logical at the moment but they didn't work. I am not very expirienced in OpenGL ES 2.0 in android.

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
mAngle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

t.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

All of these matrices are size 16 float arrays. My question is, how could I do a translation with an x and y position and sam for scale (a float with the scale)? There seems to be mo setTranslateM method and, when I tried the alternative methods I was not able to make them work. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To translate/scale/rotate your objects, you should apply these operations to your Model Matrix.

Example:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mMMatrix, 0); // reset transformations
Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0, 0); // set rotation
Matrix.translateM(mMMatrix, 0, 10.0f, 20.0f, 0); // apply translation
Matrix.scaleM(mMMatrix, 0, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f); // apply scale
```

Please note that certain static methods of `Matrix` class do memory allocations so if you do objects transformation on each frame you may want not to use them. Read more about this here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b30dd2a437cfb076?pli=1 and in my blog post here http://androidworks-kea.blogspot.com/2012/05/developers-notes-about-opengl-es.html